# How can I improve this GPA calculation code?

Tags: c++

I did this assignment for a class where a user enters 10 grades for each course, converts the letter grade into a numeric value (e.g. "A" = 4) and multiply it by the number of credits for the course and the program would calculate the GPA from there. It works great, but I would like to improve this so when the user enters a grade, it won't be any random value other than "A", "B", "C", "D", and "F".

Any ideas? I know a loop is involved, but I don't know where to start. Here's my code:

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    //declare variables to store grades, credits, courses and numeric grades
    string letterGrade[10]; //this variable is used to store the user's grades so that we can turn them into numbers
    double numericGrade[10];
    string courses[10] = { "MATH100", "ENG100", "BIO250", "ITM100", "CIS250", "HIST101", "CALC100", "SCI201", "SOC110", "PHY100" };
    int creditForCourses[10] = { 5, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4 };
    double gpa = 0.00;
    int i;

    //this for loop asks the user to enter a grade for each of their courses
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "Enter grade for: " << courses[i] << endl;
        cin >> letterGrade[i];
        }


        //the loop converts the letter grade into a numeric value
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (letterGrade[i] == "A") {
            numericGrade[i] = 4; //for each if statement, turn a specific letter grade into a value and store it into numericGrade
            }
            else
            if (letterGrade[i] == "B") {
            numericGrade[i] = 3.5;
            }
            else
            if (letterGrade[i] == "C") {
            numericGrade[i] = 3;
            }
            else
            if (letterGrade[i] == "D") {
            numericGrade[i] = 2.5;
            }
            else
            if (letterGrade[i] == "F") {
            numericGrade[i] = 0;
            }
    }





        //calculate gpa by multipling each grade value and each credit from courses
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            gpa += (numericGrade[i] * creditForCourses[i]);
        }

        //divide each numeric grade and credit and divide it by 35 (the total amount of credits)
        gpa /= 35;

        //print overall gpa for the student
        cout << "Your GPA is: " << gpa << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to validate and restrict user input to 'A' to 'F'?

Comment: Yes. I apologize for not being specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop that asks the user to enter a grade for each of their courses there you can restrict user to input valid grade. Here's the code that may work.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter grade for: " << courses[i] << endl;
    char grd;
    cin>>grd;
    if(grd=='A'||grd=='B'||grd=='C'||grd=='D'||grd=='F')
      letterGrade[i] = grd;
    else
    {
        cout<<"Please enter valid grade(A, B, C, D, F)"<<endl;
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: One question, does i-- go back to an element of the array if the value is invalid?

Comment: If a value is not valid then re-ask to enter grade of same course. i-- actually diminish the effect of increment of for loop as i remain same. So without valid grade you can not go further.

Comment: I've noticed that if you enter an invalid grade for the first element, an error will occur because the index is changed to -1 which doesn't exist in the array.

Comment: But when i becomes -1, it doesn't check with array because it is the last statement. After that statement control flow go to for loop's increment section (i++) and i becomes 0, which is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Just after

```
 else
      if (letterGrade[i] == "F") {
          numericGrade[i] = 0;
      }
```

add

```
else {
    cout << "Enter a real grade (A, B, C, D, E, F)" << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

You can instead loop until they enter a correct grade. That'd be better design, but that's an exercise left to the reader...

Comment: I would like to give the user another chance to enter the grades instead of ending the program if they entered an incorrect grade once.

Comment: Hint: Use a loop inside of the loop. (`while !answerValid`)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to wrap the code that asks the user for input with a conditional loop when an invalid value is entered. Along with a small refactoring, try like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cout << "Enter grade for: " << courses[i] << endl;
    for(int done = 0; !done;) {
        cin >> letterGrade[i];

        done = 1; // will be reset back to 0 if no "legal" character is entered

        //the loop converts the letter grade into a numeric value
        if (letterGrade[i] == "A") {
            numericGrade[i] = 4;
        }
        else if (letterGrade[i] == "B") {
            numericGrade[i] = 3.5;
        }
        else if (letterGrade[i] == "C") {
            numericGrade[i] = 3;
        }
        else if (letterGrade[i] == "D") {
            numericGrade[i] = 2.5;
        }
        else if (letterGrade[i] == "F") {
            numericGrade[i] = 0;
        }
        else {
            done = 0;
        }
    }
}
```